# Syntaxhighlighter autoloader

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting

I got the SyntaxHighlighter from http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/

I cant get the autoloader to work. What am I doing wrong?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="styles/shCore.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="styles/shCoreDefault.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="scripts/shCore.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/shAutoloader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        SyntaxHighlighter.autoloader('js scripts/shBrushJScript.js');
        SyntaxHighlighter.all();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<pre class="brush: js">
function foo()
{
}
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

I've made sure that my urls/script paths are correct.

This works, but I'd really like to get the autoloader working.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="styles/shCore.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="styles/shCoreDefault.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="scripts/shCore.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/shBrushJScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        SyntaxHighlighter.all();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<pre class="brush: js">
function foo()
{
}
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6):

To make "SyntaxHighlighter.autoloader" work, you should move the line under your "pre" sections or put it into document ready's callback.

The "autoloader" method checks current loaded "pre" sections and requests corresponding brushes. So if it's executed before the body element loaded, no brush will be loaded.

Answer (score 6):

My answer deals with the latest version of SyntaxHighlighter at the time of writing, which is version 3.0.83.

I was also having this problem and then I tried the alternative syntax for the `autoloader`  function and it worked for me even with relative paths. Please put the following code at the bottom of your page **below** all your `<pre>` tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/shCore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/shAutoloader.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    SyntaxHighlighter.autoloader(
    ['js','jscript','javascript','js/shBrushJScript.js'],
    ['bash','shell','js/shBrushBash.js'],
    ['css','js/shBrushCss.js'],
    ['xml','js/shBrushXml.js'],
    ['sql','js/shBrushSql.js'],
    ['php','js/shBrushPhp.js']
    );
    SyntaxHighlighter.all();
</script>
```

Please note that the documentation about the alternative syntax on the [SyntaxHighlighter website here](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/manual/api/autoloader.html) is currently **wrong**. It suggests that you put in an array within an array and also that you must use full paths. Both are misleading statements because the following does **not** work and no error is thrown either:

```
SyntaxHighlighter.autoloader([ [ 'alias1', 'alias2', '/full/path/to/brush.js' ] ])
```

The truth is that to use the alternative syntax you just put in a series of arrays (no parent array is required!), like so and can have relative or absolute paths:

```
SyntaxHighlighter.autoloader([ 'alias1', 'alias2', 'path/to/brush.js' ], [ 'alias1', 'alias2', 'path/to/brush2.js' ]),
```

Additionally, I must note that I had a problem with using the unminified version of SyntaxHighlighter (the file under the `src` folder bundled with SyntaxHighlighter). It was asking for the `XRegExp` library which can be downloaded here: http://xregexp.com/. However, even after including this library (which for some reason does **not** need to be included in the minified version - very strange I know!) the code was still throwing errors. In summary, I used the minified version (available under the `scripts` directory) with no problems.

To finish off this answer, here is my fully working SyntaxHighlighter autoloader code:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Hello SyntaxHighlighter</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles/shCore.css"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles/shThemeDefault.css"/>
</head>

<body style="background: white; font-family: Helvetica">

<h1>Hello SyntaxHighlighter</h1>
<pre class="brush: js;">
function helloSyntaxHighlighter()
{
    return "hi!";
}
</pre>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/shCore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/shAutoloader.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    SyntaxHighlighter.autoloader(
    ['js','jscript','javascript','js/shBrushJScript.js'],
    ['bash','shell','js/shBrushBash.js'],
    ['css','js/shBrushCss.js'],
    ['xml','js/shBrushXml.js'],
    ['sql','js/shBrushSql.js'],
    ['php','js/shBrushPhp.js']
    );
    SyntaxHighlighter.all();
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function ()
    {
        SyntaxHighlighter.autoloader('js scripts/shBrushJScript.js');
        SyntaxHighlighter.all();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For people reading this in future, for some reason the shAutoloader.js script's path is locked in...

Meaning if you want it to auto load you're going to have to put it in this specific path:
`js/syntaxhighlighter/shAutoloader.js` along with the rest of the language scripts.

It's stupid but if anyone knows how to fix this, let me know :D

Comment: There is no truth to this whatsoever, I have tested this and it works with any type of relative path. I also analysed the source code and there is no specific path convention as you're suggesting

Answer (score 0):

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="styles/shCore.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="styles/shCoreDefault.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="scripts/shCore.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/shAutoloader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>


<pre class="brush: js">
function foo()
{
}
</pre>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        SyntaxHighlighter.autoloader('js scripts/shBrushJScript.js');
        SyntaxHighlighter.all();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please ellaborate your answer a little more, pointing what was wrong and what should be done.